# Optimization Problem, am I doing this properly?

Tags: calculus, optimization

I'm not 100% sure on my maths for this question, so I figured I'd double check it here.

A box with a square base and open top must have a volume of $32,000 cm^3$. Find the dimension of the box that minimize the amount of material used.

---

The constraint is that $V=32,000cm^3$, the size of the box will be $=x^2+4xy$

Putting the size into one variable will become, $=x^2+4x(\frac{32000}{x^2})$

Calculating the derivative will result in $2x-\frac{128000}{x^2}$

The critical points...

$2x-\frac{128000}{x^2} = 0$

$\frac{-128000}{x^2}=-2x$

$\frac{128000}{2}=\frac{2x^3}{2}$

$64000=x^3$

$40=x$

---

$f(x) = x^2+4x(\frac{32000}{x^2})$

$f(40) = 40^2+4(40)(\frac{32000}{40^2})$

$=1600+160(\frac{32000}{1600})$

$=1600+3200$

$=4800$

---

Did I do this properly? I'm not sure as I've always struggled with these problems, if not can someone point out what was wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The right answer was obtained, with a correct method. You might be expected to give an argument that this really gives the minimum area. (As an aside, note that the optimal box is a cube cut in the middle.)